# How to delete an instance if cpu is low?

Tags: automation, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, monitoring

I am running managed Instance groups whose overall c.p.u is always below 30% but if i check instances individually then i found some are running at 70 above and others are running as low as 15 percent.

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Do you have session affinity enabled? What type of traffic are you serving and its backend requirements (simple HTML requests, database processing, CPU intensive operations, etc. FridayPush's answer has good information to help you figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Managed Instance Groups don't take into account individual instances as whether a machine should be removed from the pool or not. GCP's MIGs keep a running average of the last 10 minutes of activity of all instances in the group and use that metric to determine scaling decisions. You can find more [details here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions).

Identifying instances with lower CPU usage than the group doesn't seem like the right goal here, instead I would suggest focusing on *why* some machines have 15% usage and others have 70%. How is work distributed to your instances, are you using the correct strategies for load balancing for your workload?

Maybe your applications have specific endpoints that cause large amounts of CPU usage while the majority of them are basic CRUD operations, having one machine generating a report and displaying higher usage is fine. If all instances render HTML pages from templates and return the results one machine performing much less work than the others is a distribution issue. Maybe you're using a [RPS algorithm when you want a CPU utilization one](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps#requests_per_second_rps).

Comment: In our Buissness model each vm works separately so there is no pint of adding load balancing concept. I just want that if a vm in instance group is working below 15% so then statckdriver should through an alert or some kind of metric i could use to delete that low cpu instance only . we want above 80 % cpu ,that is desirable for us .

Comment: I don't believe MIG is what you're looking for. For example if you were to go in manually and delete a 15% usage instance, the MIG would recreate it determines a need for that many instances. Perhaps an unmanaged instance group is what you're looking for, combined with Jason's suggestions for Stackdriver alerting: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, the best option is to create an Alert notification that will alert you when an instance goes over the desired CPU usage. Once you receive the notification, you will then be able to manually delete the VM instance. As it is part of the Managed Instance group, the VM instance will automatically recreate.

I have attached an article on how to create an Alert notification [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options).

There is no metric within Stackdriver that will call the GCE API to delete a VM instance .

Comment: but i don't want to delet it manually as at sometimes we are running 400-500 instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such automation in place. It should't be too difficult to implement it yourself though. You can write a small script that would run on all your machines (started from Cron or something) that monitors CPU usage. If it decides it is too low, the instance can delete itself from the MIG (you can use e.g. gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances  --instances ).